# how to finish space between inline label and textbox in flex box css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

this is y code

```
 <div _ngcontent-c45="" class="col-sm-6 formControlDiv" fxflex="" ng-reflect-flex="" > <label _ngcontent-c45="" class="control-label" for="Reference" style="background: blue;
color: white;">Reference</label> <input _ngcontent-c45="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ref" disabled="" id="Reference" name="Reference" placeholder="Reference" ng-reflect-name="Reference" ng-reflect-is-disabled="" ng-reflect-model="BTR-3-TEST" value="BTR-3-TEST"> </div>
```

Reference

[image]

Comment: and where is flexbox and bootstrap on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<label>` and `<input>` have `display:inline`.

To simplify things a bit, you should consider any inline element a simple letter. And you have a space between your letters: `...</label> <input... >`.

When you type `foo bar` you expect the browser to output: `foo bar`, not `foobar`. Don't expect otherwise in case of other inline elements.

```html
<div _ngcontent-c45="" class="col-sm-6 formControlDiv" fxflex="" ng-reflect-flex="" > <label _ngcontent-c45="" class="control-label" for="Reference" style="background: blue;
color: white;">Reference</label><input _ngcontent-c45="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ref" disabled="" id="Reference" name="Reference" placeholder="Reference" ng-reflect-name="Reference" ng-reflect-is-disabled="" ng-reflect-model="BTR-3-TEST" value="BTR-3-TEST"> </div>
```

If you prefer to have your tags on different rows, to increase readability and maintainability of your code, place the newline character inside the tags:

```
 </label
 ><input ...>
```

---

*Note:* if removing that space does not fix your problem, you should triple-check `margin` and `padding` on both `<label>` and `<input>`.